# Get domain for a given function (including e.g. singularities)

Tags: functions

I am new to Mathematica and this is probably a simple question, but I can't figure it out at the moment...

```
f[x_]:=1/(x-3)
```

Clearly the vertical asymptote is at `x->3`, as`1/0` is undefined.

I would like some kind of function that's output is simply:

```
3
```

I need to know where the function is undefined. Some functions give me:

`{{x->3}}` and things like that, but I can't work with that.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Hi ! Can't you just use `Solve` on the denominator ? Like this `Solve[x-3==0, x]`

Comment: You *should* try to get to grips with `Rule`d output, this will greatly enhance your *Mathematica* experience.

Comment: To follow up on what Yves said, see [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/18706#18706) to the "pitfalls" question for a nice explanation.

Answer (score 7):

### [FunctionDomain](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FunctionDomain.html)

In versions 10+, you can use the built-in `FunctionDomain`:

```
f[x_]:=1/(x-3);
FunctionDomain[f[x], x]
(* x<3||x>3 *)
Not[%]//FullSimplify
(* x == 3 *)
```

or, more directly,

```
Not[FunctionDomain[f[x], x]]//FullSimplify
(* x == 3 *)
```

To get `3` use

```
Not[FunctionDomain[f[x], x]]//FullSimplify //Last
(* 3 *)
```

Further examples:

```
Not[FunctionDomain[Tan[x], x]]//FullSimplify
(* 1/2 + x/π ∈ Integers *)

Not[FunctionDomain[(x + y)/(x^2 - y^2), {x, y}]]//FullSimplify
(* x^2==y^2 *)
```

Thanks: @BobHanlon for the comment that `Reals` is the default domain, and hence, `FunctionDomain[f[x], x, Reals` is equivalent to `FunctionDomain[f[x], x]`.

For version 9,

```
Not[Reduce[Abs@f[x] < Infinity, x, Reals]] // FullSimplify // Last
(* 3 *)
```

Comment: +1 The default domain is `Reals` so there is no need to specify the domain.

Comment: Thank you @Bob. I will revise the post accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have V10 yet, so I am just going to extend @Sektor.

Let say you have a function with some divergences. I choose here a simple example like

```
f[x_] = Product[1/(x - a[i]), {i, 3}]
```

You can get the poles by

```
Solve[1/f[x] == 0, x]
```

It works if you have two variables as well like

```
f[x_, y_] = Product[1/(x + y - a[i]), {i, 3}]
Solve[1/f[x, y] == 0, x]
```

Now the final answer may depend on how complex your initial function is. You may get an conditional expression or in worst case you may have to go for a numerical solution.