# Is there a built-in function which detects singularities in a function?

Tags: functions, calculus-and-analysis

Given a function `f[x]` and a region M in the complex x-plane, how can I find singularities of `f` in this region, i.e., issue a command to *Mathematica* which returns the type of singularity and its parameters?

Let me be more specific

1. discontinuities (jumps)
2. poles
3. branch points

Examples

```
f[x_] := Sin[x] Sign[Cos[x]]
g[x_] := 1/(a - x)^2
h[x_] := Sqrt[x + b]
```

**EDIT 11.09.14**
The restriction to real x in my first version of the text was not a good idea. I have changed it.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/58926/131?

Comment: The reference covers only my example g.

Comment: I agree with Hintze. This is not a duplicate of 58326

Comment: If you really mean to restrict your question to built-in functions, I am not aware of such a function.

Comment: Are `a` and `b` always real? Are the parameters in the functions symbolic, or are they all numerical? I assume `a` in `g[x]` isn't the same as the interval boundary `a`? I.e., are you looking for numerical or symbolic solutions?

Comment: There must be something (possibly undocumented) because the exclusion detection feature of Plot does exactly this.

Comment: @Szabolcs That's true - it may even be part of the symbolic processing step. For example, if I define `ff[x_?NumericQ] := Sign[x]` then `Plot[ff[x], {x, -1, 1}, ExclusionsStyle -> Red]` doesn't show any detected exclusions.

Comment: To begin with, I was mainly thinking of jumps, as we had the discussion about definite integrals in the case when the antiderivative is not continious. But the question is more general.

Comment: This is closely related [How to find the non-differentiable point(s) of a given continuous function?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/32872/how-to-find-the-non-differentiable-points-of-a-given-continuous-function) or simply a duplicate.

Comment: @Artes I agree on the closeness because the intention here was originally to find points of non-differentiability, too. But I interpreted the usage of "singularity" here to be more general. E.g., `Abs[x]^2` would be differentiable but still singular.

Answer (score 12):

I don't think there's a general function built in that can deal with all possible cases. But `Reduce` is quite powerful. Here is a function that seems to work for the last two examples given:

```
singularCondition[func_, variable_] := 
 Reduce[1/func[variable] == 0 || 
   1/func'[variable] == 0, variable, Reals]

singularCondition[h, x]

(* ==> x == -b *)

singularCondition[g, x]

(* ==> x == a *)

singularCondition[f, x]

(*
==> False
*)
```

The last case doesn't detect a singularity for `f[x]`, so jumps will require more work.

I added the restriction to the real domain because the question explicitly specifies an interval on the real line. This condition could also be removed.

The problem is that singularities could occur in arbitrarily high derivatives, too. And that's not so easy to check with my approach.

**Edit**

The following approach does a little better with a discontinuous function, in that it at least gives you an indication that **something** is preventing the function from being analytic:

```
analyticityCondition[func_, variable_] := Module[{n, c},
  TrueQ@SumConvergence[
    x^n Simplify[SeriesCoefficient[func[variable], {variable, c, n}], 
      n >= 0], n]
  ]

analyticityCondition[h, x]

(* ==> False *)

analyticityCondition[g, x]

(* ==> False *)

analyticityCondition[f, x]

(* ==> False *)

analyticityCondition[Sin, x]

(* ==> True *)
```

This works by asking for the Taylor expansion of the given function around a *generic* origin `c`, and then invoking `SumConvergence` to see if the coefficients of that expansion for non-negative powers indeed yield a convergent sum. A negative result for the test `TrueQ` could mean *either* that *Mathematica* wasn't able to deal with the expansion, *or* the sum has a finite radius of convergence (which means there is some singularity). Only if you get the result `True` can you be sure that the function has no singularities.

So I would use this analyticity test first, and if it returns `False` you can apply the earlier function `singularityCondition` to find where things go wrong. Then if this step finds nothing, you still know that a singularity *could* nevertheless be hiding somewhere (as in the case of `f[x]`).

The function `analyticityCondition` can also detect the *existence* of singularities in higher derivatives:

```
k[x_] := Abs[x]^2

analyticityCondition[k, x]

(* ==> False *)
```

This is a differentiable function, but not analytic at `0`.

Comment: Thanks. Will study it in detail. Short question: what does the apostrophe in func' mean?

Comment: `'`: `Derivative`  funny though, the online help does returns nothing for `'`.

Comment: @Jens: very good idea, in priciple. But here are some more examples: analyticityCondition[#, x] & /@ {# &, Sin, Exp, Log[1 + #] &, Tan, Sqrt, Floor, Sign, Gamma[1 + #] &, 
 Zeta[2 + #] &, Erf} (* all return False except the first three *)

Comment: @Yves: oh, stupid me. Didn't I know that since school times ;-)

Comment: @Jens: I don't understand the local parameter c. It has the meaning of the point x0 around which Series makes the Expansion. But it has no values assigned!? If I drop it from the Parameter list, your function ceases to work correctly. Please explain.

Comment: @Jens: you singularCondition (i.e. Reduce) works very well also in the complex Domain (if we drop Reals, calling it singularConditionC). singularConditionC[1/(1 + #1^2) & , x] -> x == -I || x == I. It even works with Zeta and gives a prudent answer: singularConditionC[1/Zeta[#1] & , x] -> Reduce::rhyp:Warning: Reduce assumed the Riemann hypothesis in order to prove the solution set found is complete. >> Element[C[1], Integers] && ((C[1] >= 1 && x == -2*C[1]) || (C[1] != 0 && x == ZetaZero[C[1]])) (1+)

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze I added the arbitrary `c` because I can't specify a numerical expansion center, since that may happen to be a special point of singularity. E.g., `1/x` can't be expanded around `0`, but it can be expanded around `c`. So I avoid unnecessary error messaged this way. Maybe this could be eliminated if instead I catch such errors differently...

Answer (score 4):

It might be interesting for you to compare @Jens' answer with `FunctionDomain` (new in **V10**):

```
compare[fun_] := {
  fun[x],
  FunctionDomain[fun[x], x, Reals],
  FunctionDomain[fun[x], x, Complexes],
  analyticityCondition[fun, x],
  singularCondition[fun, x]}

TableForm[
 compare /@ {Sin, Tan, f, g, h},
 TableHeadings ->
  {None, {"Function", "RealDomain", "ComplexDomain",
    "analyticityCondition", "singularCondition", "RealRange"}},
 TableSpacing -> {3, 3}]
```

[image]

Comment: Clearly `FunctionDomain` can yield `True` for non-analytic functions, such as the third one (or anything with singularities in higher derivatives). But it does detect the `Tan` singularities (as does my answer).

Comment: @Jens I certainly would use your (updated) definitions. Hopefully, in V11 or later we see something like "AnalyticQ", "HarmonicQ" etc.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

https://reference.wolframcloud.com/language/ref/FunctionSingularities.html

For instance:

```
FunctionSingularities[Tan[x], x]
```

or

```
FunctionSingularities[ArcTan[x^y], {x, y}, Complexes]
```